# Laravel Validator check if field satisfies preferred value and make the other field required?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Currently I have working `validator` in my `Request` folder

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ahiTitle' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'ahiDesc' => ['string'],
        'ahiDate' => ['required'],
        'ahiType' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'attachment' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048']
    ];
}
```

for the field of `ahiType` I have 2 different expected values to be received

`COURSE` AND `FACILITY`

I'm trying to do if the rules finds out that the value of `ahiType` is `FACILITY`

This will rule out that the field `ahiDate` is required but if the  `ahiType` has the value of `COURSE`

the `ahiDate` should be nullable means not required. Is that possible?

---

Note: I can filter it using jquery validation but I just want to use `validator` since all my validations are stated in here.

Answer (score 1):

```
"ahiDate" => "required_if:ahiType,==,FACILITY"
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: It reads, ahiDate is required if ahiType is FACILITY, otherwise it is not required.    You stated, If the field ahiType is FACILITY then ahiDate is required,  otherwise it's not.  The alternative it you really need to check for COURSE specifically is to create a custom RULE